# Matlab surface plot of 3 related values

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

I am pretty new at MatLab and I need help creating this surface plot. I have some drilling speeds, feeding speeds and the quality percentage of each hole. I have saved each of these values in different arrays (x, y and z). How do I plot a surface showing the quality over the drilling and feeding speeds? I have been searching some tutorials on youtube but couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for. I'd appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Look about on the help about `surface`, `surf`, `mesh` and `meshgrid`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a set of points in 3D-space, where each dimension represent either drilling speed, feeding speed or quality percentage. A point on a surface is on the form (x, y, f(x,y)), not (x, y, z). Maybe you want to plot a point cloud? A point cloud can be plotted as follows:

```
N_POINTS = 100;
points = rand(100, 3);
X = points(:, 1);
Y = points(:, 2);
Z = points(:, 3);
scatter3(X, Y, Z, '.')
```

See https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html for more information on usage of `scatter3`